# Cant print text with html xpath with selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I'm trying to make a temporary email generator using 20-minute mail, but I can seem to print the text from my XPath. I started python 2 months ago and have been getting really good answers with my other questions. any response is appreciated.
code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("http://www.20minutemail.com/")
sleep(1)
createMail = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"headerwrap\"]/header/div[2]/div/div/input[2]")
createMail.click()
sleep(3)
email = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"userTempMail\"]/text()")
print(email)
```

Comment: _but I can seem to print the text from my XPath_ I'll assume you meant "can't" instead of "can".  What happens when you try to print it?  Do you get an error?  Does something get printed that you weren't expecting?

Answer (score 0):

I've got similar problems when I tried to get some kind of attribute using xpath. I'm still not sure why. I worked arround it using the WebElement attribute. Try this:

`email = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"userTempMail\"]).text`

Also, if you want to optimize your code you change `sleep(time)` for `WebDriverWait(driver, time).until(some_condition)`. This'll stop halting your code as soon as some_condition is met. More on this here: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits

Comment: i used the line but get a " EOL while scanning string literal" error. but thanks for telling me about the webdriverWait command!

Answer (score 0):

I changed it to

```
email = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"userTempMail\"]")
```

(taking the /text() out so it knows its just html)
then doing

```
print(email.text)
```

to get the inner text out.